# How does an EBS volume in an Availability zone get restricted only to a specific AWS account & its users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

In AWS, an EC2 instance is launched within a subnet created in an Availability Zone which is again, in a VPC. So, the VPC can be thought of like a container to which only the AWS account and its users have access to. But when creating EBS volumes, only the Availability Zone is asked for / provided and the same EBS volume can be attached to any EC2 instance irrespective of the VPC it belongs to (Of course, for the same AWS account only). My question is - How does AWS prevent other AWS accounts from seeing this EBS volume present in the AZ? Is that implementation abstracted by AWS?

Answer (score 1):

An **Amazon VPC** is a virtual construct that is used to connect virtual computers according to traditional networking. Resources (eg EC2 instances, RDS databases) can be connected via a VPC, which determines how network traffic flows between them. It is not necessarily how the resources are *physically* created.

An **Availability Zone** is a physical data center (or a group of data centers). Resources are created in an AZ, which determines their physical location. For example, an Amazon EBS volume resides in a data center, so it is in only one AZ. It can be logically connected to any EC2 instance in the same account in the same AZ.

Amazon EBS volumes are connected via a backplane that is invisible to the resources. It just magically "attaches" to the instance. It does not use the same network as a VPC.

The Amazon EBS service will only provide EBS volumes to EC2 instances in the same AWS account.

Comment: Thank you John. I am trying to understand if the Account itself is the outermost envelope for the resources it creates and isolates resources between accounts. This concept gets confusing with S3 buckets because the ARN for S3 bucket does not contain the Account number but that S3 bucket is "somehow" bound to that account when first created. I am trying to understand the "virtual envelope" that binds a resource to the account that creates it - Is that AWS internal magic?

Comment: An Amazon S3 bucket ARN does not contain an account number because every bucket name is unique. Therefore, the ARN is unique without the account number and region. Yes, it is all handled internally by AWS.

Comment: Thank you John. Much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS Shared Responsibility Model](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/):

> AWS responsibility “Security of the Cloud” - AWS is responsible for
>   protecting the infrastructure that runs all of the services offered in
>   the AWS Cloud. This infrastructure is composed of the hardware,
>   software, networking, and facilities that run AWS Cloud services.

AWS provides isolation of all resources between accounts, and this implementation is abstracted, and a part of AWS responsibility.

In addition, it is recommended to [Encrypt EBS Volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSEncryption.html), it is free and doesn't impact volume performance.

Comment: Thank you Igor, but why does AWS not give EBS the same flexibility as EC2 i.e. to choose Subnet? Is it because it might become too overwhelming for a user ?

Comment: I will rephrase my question just to be sure we both are on same page.For an AWS account/user, a EC2 instance is bound by a Subnet in an AZ and then by a VPC but an EBS that gets attached to EC2 is only bound at AZ level - no reference to VPC or Subnet. Does that mean that there is some other mechanism that binds EBS to a user which is abstracted from us and prevents other users (hosting EC2 on the same AZ) from seeing the EBS volume?

Comment: Correct, there is some mechanism behind that isolates all resources from one account from any resources from any other account, including EBS. There is no real  value of binding EBS to subnet within VPC, as EBS can be used with EC2 only, and you already have EC2 placed in some subnet. 
And to be clear -  VPC and subnets is not something you use for network isolation from other accounts, it is something you use to isolate resources from each other within YOUR account.